# Domain Model Namespace naming conventions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, naming-conventions, domain-model

### Issue:

For asp.net mvc apps, I ignore the domain folder and write the domain model in a separate library project.

Visual Studio, with such a library project, will namespace on a folder by folder basis.  Eg, if my library project is called:

ES.eLearning.Domain

and I have a folder called Services, it will auto namespace all classes in the Services folder as:

ES.eLearning.Domain.Services

Which is all well and good, but strikes me as overkill. My projects are relatively simple and so there is no chance of class name clashes.  Even if there were, the compiler would pick it up.

So I just manually edit the namespace names to the project name, ie:

ES.eLearning.Domain

That way, when developing the front end, the domain model project is just a black box that delivers, well, a domain model.  And I don't see the point of coupling the namespace names to the projects folder structure, as opposed to treating it as one functional block.

### So two questions arise:

1. Is this bad practice?  If so, why?  Remember: these are small to medium projects.
2. Is there a way to tell VS 2010 how to name my namespaces?

Thanks

Note:  In my naming of the project, ES is the client, eLearning is the app, Domain is the component

PS: other questions on namespace naming conventions I have found on SO address different issues.  So not a duplicate as far as I can determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a particular folder forcing its contents to use the folder name as a namespace part, you can right-click the folder, choose "Properties" and then change "Namespace Provider" to `False`. That would need to be done to all the folders to which it applies though, so I'm not sure if that's really answered your question fully.

**Edit**: looks like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) adds this functionality.

Comment: The only property I see is folder name...  I have found that Namespace Provider is a ReSharper property.

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right. Sorry - I haven't got a machine without R# installed to check with before answering and I assumed it was a VS thing. I assume a R#-specific answer is not a viable solution for you?

Comment: No answers quite fit the bill, but this answer brought ReSharper into focus.  So have given it the biscuit.

Answer (score 1):

Coaxing your IDE to use a naming convention that suits your particular environment is good practice. You can use the default namespace box in the Application tab of the project properties to change the namespace that VS automatically inserts in your class files.

Comment: Thanks, grenade: +1 for the bit about good practice.  However, your tip about the default namespace name won't stop VS adding the folder name onto my default namespace name.  (NOTE:  the default namespace name defaults to the project name which is fine with me; my issue is with the IDE adding the folder name to the namespace declaration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it possible to configure in VS2010 to disable this.. but I would not do that.

If your code file placed in Domain folder, its namespace should be Company.Domain. If domain has sub folder Services, namespace should be Company.Domain.Services. It is a good (and whats important - common, practice).

You better stick to the rules, over violating them :)

Comment: alexanderb:  it is always good to question the rules.  The rules are not always good:  I started with MS Access and VBA and took an instant dislike to the "standard", ie, Leszynski naming convention.  It doesn't port anywhere out of Access and doesn't take account of modern intellisense.  But so be it, I listen.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions to use singular ending while naming namespaces, folders and classes. For example

```
namespace ES.eLearning.Domain.Services
```

would be preffered as

```
ES.eLearning.Domain.Service // <-- note missing "s"
```

And another example of usage in source code:

```
ES.eLearning.Domain.Constants.FileTypes.Text
```

could be "better" to understand as

```
ES.eLearning.Domain.Constant.FileType.Text
```

---

It is all of the personal preferences and it is not a rule. Just a small thing that might make the code (namespace)  shorter and easier to read at the same time.

PS. On the other hand ASP.NET MVC does not follow this "rule":

```
Content
Controllers
Models
Scripts
Views
```

But nothing keeps you "renaming" them in the source code anyway.

Comment: @J Pollack:  I disagree with that one.  I think of a namespace as something that holds things, eg, Services, or FileTypes.  For example, Text is just one of many FileTypes.

Comment: Well I just wanted to show there is another way. In database context it makes sense.
Using plural table names, writing a query that gives something like:

SELECT tags.name, tags.description FROM tags WHERE tags.xxx = YYY; 

and the "tags.name" looks a little weird because it's looks like an attribute access in a lot of language.
Excuse the off topic :)